# Deja-Dup: "Backup location not available"

Tags: mount, backup, deja-dup

My internal backup drive is mounted, but when I try to start a backup, or recover missing files, I get the above message. It also says "Waiting for [device] to become available" (translated from French).

[This similar question](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228988) was not useful. I tried creating a folder called "deja-dup" on the backup device, but nothing changed. I have also tried unmounting and remounting the drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the drive itself (not the mount point) set as the backup location, but for some reason the drive just isn't recognized as connected. Here's what I did:

1. In the deja-dup settings, set "Storage location" as "local folder"
2. Set "Folder" as the backup folder on the filesystem. In my case, `/mnt/Earth/Backup/Ubuntu home`

Comment: In my case the backup location was an external drive mounted on USB. Backup claimed it could not connect after upgrading to 18.04. Odd because there was a working connection. Using a local folder as described above did the trick.